# PLS-00321 Error

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have declared a record as below

```
TYPE pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec IS RECORD (
   user_id npe_user.user_id%TYPE,
   Portal_grp_name npe_portal_grp.protal_group_name%TYPE
);
```

When am using the same value in the below procedure am getting error

```
PROCEDURE add_rmv_usr_portal_grp (
                       p_user_portal_grp   IN   pg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab,
                       p_status            OUT   VARCHAR2 )
Begin
pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec := p_user_portal_grp;
```

**Error :**

```
02:34:11.795    DBMS    npeproc -- PLS-00321: expression 'PG_WAD_USR_PORTGRP_REC' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression does not designate a variable that can have a value assigned to it. For example, the function SYSDATE cannot appear on the left hand side of an assignment statement

TYPE pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec IS RECORD ( user_id npe_user.user_id%TYPE)
pg_wad_usr_portgrp_data pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec;

Answer (score 0):

First, definition is pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec and parameter type pg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab so not sure if you need to use composite type or collection of composite type. Anyway you cannot assign value to type definition.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec IS RECORD 
  (
     user_id npe_user.user_id%TYPE,
     Portal_grp_name npe_portal_grp.protal_group_name%TYPE
  );

  TYPE pg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab IS TABLE OF pg_wad_usr_portgrp_rec;

  PROCEDURE add_rmv_usr_portal_grp (
           p_user_portal_grp   IN   pg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab,
           p_status            OUT   VARCHAR2) AS

    lpg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab pg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab;
  BEGIN
    lpg_wad_usr_portgrp_tab := p_user_portal_grp;
  END;
BEGIN
  null;
END;
/
```